# How can get date in daterangepicker ranges selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I have to use daterangepicker and I can't figure out how to fetch the selected date in jquery.

```
 $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
}, cb);

//fetch seleted date
var get_date = $('#reportrange').val()

console.log("reportrange selected date:", get_date)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Date Range Picker selected date to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364524/how-do-i-get-date-range-picker-selected-date-to-a-variable)

Comment: Yes i have tried this but it fetches current date `Thu Jan 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530`

Comment: So you should format it accordingly, like `.format('DD-MM-YYYY')` with every format as you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must retrieve the data object:

```
$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate;
$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate;
```

You can also use this

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({ opens: 'left' }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("Your Select date range is: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
</script>
```

For more detail : https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use default callback function like this

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
   }, 
   function(start, end, label) {
       console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' 
        to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});

$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate;
$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate;
```